# POST method is not work while creating API in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, api, post

I have created API for Login using POST method but it give me error 
GET method is work.

[Post data through postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEjry.jpg)

code of student_login method of contrller Api

class Api extends CI_Controller{

public function student_login()
    {

```
    $username=$this->input->post['vUserName'];
    $password=$this->input->post['vPassword'];

    $this->load->model('Api_model');

    $result=$this->Api_model->get_login($username,$password);
    if(!empty($result))
    {
        $response["error"]="true";
        $response["message"]="You have been successfully login";
        echo json_encode(array('result'=>$result));
        die( json_encode($response));
    }
    else
    {
        $response["error"]="false";
        $response["message"]="Invalid Username and Password";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }





}
```

}

Model :To load the data of table tbl_students

class Api_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function get_login($name,$pass)
    {
        //echo $name,$pass;
        $this->db->select('iStudentID,class,section,vDivision,vGrno');
        $this->db->from('tbl_students');

```
    $this->db->where('vUserName',$name);

    $this->db->where('vPassword',$pass);

   //$this->db->from('tbl_students');
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();

}
```

}

Comment: How are you posting the form like ajax ? , share the form php code

Comment: Posting from postman tool

Comment: can you post the postman screenshot

Comment: your student login controller code please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Implementation is right, but you can't check the post method through your browser. Try some other tools like [postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop).